# How do I call a function from another .py file?

Tags: python, file, function, import

`file.py` contains a function named `function`. How do I import it?

```
from file.py import function(a,b)
```

The above gives an error:

> ImportError: No module named 'file.py'; file is not a package

Comment: `from file import function`. No need for file extensions or function parameters

Comment: You should probably go through the [modules section](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) in the Python tutorial.

Comment: Also if you want to import the function from the `file.py`, make sure there is no package in your directory with the name `file`.

Comment: If you have an ImportError or a ModuleError see this question, it was very helpful for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279446/import-error-no-module-named-xxxx/33615230#33615230

Comment: `from your_file_name import *` works for me

Answer (score 840, accepted):

First, import `function` from `file.py`:

```
from file import function
```

Later, call the function using:

```
function(a, b)
```

Note that `file` is one of Python's core modules, so I suggest you change the filename of `file.py` to something else.

Note that if you're trying to import functions from `a.py` to a file called `b.py`, you will need to make sure that `a.py` and `b.py` are in the same directory.

Comment: The "file" was just a placeholder for the question I am asking, not the actual file name. Thank you though.  I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: I tried this, but it is still showing the error: Has it got anything to do with Python 3, or is a general problem?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, what if the file you want to import functions from is in a different directory? Can I include the filepath preceeding the filename, or is there something more complicated?

Comment: @Tom You have to add that path to the PYTHONPATH variable if it is not already in there.

Comment: Is there a way to import functions from a.py to a file b.py if they are not in the same directory?

Comment: newbies try "import file", which should execute only once (singleton)

Comment: Do you have to import all dependencies from `file` that are used in `function` as well?

Comment: In Python 2 it looks like this either (a) executes the entire script you're referencing with `from foo import ...` or (b) does not work if `foo.py` has references to the `argparse` library.

Comment: @DarkRose Same for me, I fixed it by changing the order of the imports within __init__.py file, making sure root dependencies were loaded after their transitive dependencies.

Comment: Didn't work with a hyphen in the filename, e.g. `from fil-e import *`.

Comment: For those coming from a javascript background, note that you don't need quotes around the file name in the import. Also, if it's in a different directory, you can do `from myDirectory.someSubDirectory.myFile import yay`.

Answer (score 307):

Do not write `.py` when importing.

Let `file_a.py` contain some functions inside it:

```
def f():
  return 1

def g():
  return 2
```

To import these functions into `file_z.py`, do this:

```
from file_a import f, g
```

Comment: you can also import *

Comment: @DimitarMarinov With * replaced by the filename?

Comment: @Karlo, no, just *

Comment: using "import *" is considered a bad practice. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: If a.py is in a folder say fol1, then how shall it be imported? @dimitar-marinov

Comment: @AdityaC add the folder to your PYTHONPATH is one way

Comment: Dimitar Marinov means this: `from a import *`

Answer (score 114):

If your file is in the different package structure and you want to call it from a different package, then you can call it in that fashion:

Let's say you have following package structure in your python project:

[image: Python package and file structure]

in - `com.my.func.DifferentFunction` python file you have some function, like:

```
def add(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2

def sub(arg1, arg2) :
    return arg1 - arg2

def mul(arg1, arg2) :
    return arg1 * arg2
```

And you want to call different functions from `Example3.py`, then following way you can do it:

Define import statement in `Example3.py` - file for import all function

```
from com.my.func.DifferentFunction import *
```

or define each function name which you want to import

```
from com.my.func.DifferentFunction import add, sub, mul
```

Then in `Example3.py` you can call function for execute:

```
num1 = 20
num2 = 10

print("\n add : ", add(num1,num2))
print("\n sub : ", sub(num1,num2))
print("\n mul : ", mul(num1,num2))
```

Output:

```
 add :  30

 sub :  10

 mul :  200
```

Comment: glob import is discouraged.

Comment: Can't resist to point out the Java like file structure... com.my.example.. kinda pokes into my eyes, though it might be just me.

Comment: WHat should be the working directory to run the code ?

Comment: I am executing this addition or multiplication function from the "Example3.py" file.

Answer (score 100):

**Method 1.** Import the specific function(s) you want from file.py:

```
from file import function
```

---

**Method 2.**  Import the entire file:

```
import file as fl
```

Then, to call any function inside file.py, use:

```
fl.function(a, b)
```

Answer (score 52):

You can call the function from a different directory as well, in case you cannot or do not want to have the function in the same directory you are working. You can do this in two ways (perhaps there are more alternatives, but these are the ones that have worked for me).

Alternative 1
Temporarily change your working directory

```
import os

os.chdir("**Put here the directory where you have the file with your function**")

from file import function

os.chdir("**Put here the directory where you were working**")
```

Alternative 2
Add the directory where you have your function to sys.path

```
import sys

sys.path.append("**Put here the directory where you have the file with your function**")

from file import function
```

Comment: isn't it the same as adding path to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: This is the one that worked for me in a special case where I wanted to 'borrow-call' some external code without copy or modification.

Answer (score 43):

To fix

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

try using a dot (`.`) in front of the filename to do a relative import:

```
from .file import function
```

Comment: Any explanation about this please ?

Comment: saved my day, thanks . '.' points to current working directory

Answer (score 40):

Functions from .py file (can (of course) be in different directory) can be simply imported by writing directories first and then the file name without .py extension:

```
from directory_name.file_name import function_name
```

And later be used: `function_name()`

Answer (score 17):

Rename the module to something other than 'file'.

Then also be sure when you are calling the function that:

1)if you are importing the entire module, you reiterate the module name when calling it:

```
import module
module.function_name()
```

or

```
import pizza
pizza.pizza_function()
```

2)or if you are importing specific functions, functions with an alias, or all functions using *, you don't reiterate the module name:

```
from pizza import pizza_function
pizza_function()
```

or

```
from pizza import pizza_function as pf
pf()
```

or

```
from pizza import *
pizza_function()
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it details how to import a file FULL of functions, and how to call them.

Answer (score 14):

First save the file in .py format (for example, `my_example.py`).
And if that file have functions,

```
def xyz():

        --------

        --------

def abc():

        --------

        --------
```

In the calling function you just have to type the below lines.

file_name: my_example2.py

============================

```
import my_example.py


a = my_example.xyz()

b = my_example.abc()
```

============================

Comment: I don't know if my fail is about python versions. What i do choosing this example is `import fn` (without extension) and using them directly on the main file `fn.my_funcion()`. When i use `import fn.py` tries to load py.py file, wich doesn't exist. Using `from fn.py import funcname` didn't work too. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

append a dot `.` in front of a file name if you want to import this file which is in the same directory where you are running your code.

For example, I'm running a file named `a.py` and I want to import a method named `addFun` which is written in `b.py`, and `b.py` is there in the same directory

```
from .b import addFun
```

Answer (score 9):

Inside MathMethod.Py.

```
def Add(a,b):
   return a+b 

def subtract(a,b):
  return a-b
```

Inside Main.Py

```
import MathMethod as MM 
  print(MM.Add(200,1000))
```

Output:1200

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to add `file.py`.

Just keep the file in the same location with the file from where you want to import it. Then just import your functions:

```
from file import a, b
```

Comment: Oh sure it doesn't. I didn't meant to type .py
It's a typo

Answer (score 6):

Solution1: In one file `myfun.py` define any function(s).

```
# functions
def Print_Text():
    print( 'Thank You')

def Add(a,b):
    c=a+b
    return c
```

In the other file:

```
#Import defined functions
from myfun import *

#Call functions
Print_Text()
c=Add(1,2)
```

Solution2: if this above solution did not work for Colab

1. Create a folder`myfun`
2. Inside this folder create a file `__init__.py`
3. Write all your functions in `__init__.py`
4. Import your functions from Colab notebook `from myfun import *`

Answer (score 5):

You should have the file at the same location as that of the Python files you are trying to import. Also 'from file import function' is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Any of the above solutions didn't work for me. I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named whtever` error.
So my solution was importing like below

```
from . import filename # without .py
```

inside my first file I have defined function fun like below

```
# file name is firstFile.py
def fun():
  print('this is fun')
```

inside the second file lets say I want to call the function fun

```
from . import firstFile

def secondFunc():
   firstFile.fun() # calling `fun` from the first file

secondFunc() # calling the function `secondFunc`
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the file you want to call is anotherfile.py and the method you want to call is method1, then first import the file and then the method

```
from anotherfile import method1
```

if method1 is part of a class, let the class be class1, then

```
from anotherfile import class1
```

then create an object of class1, suppose the object name is ob1, then

```
ob1 = class1()
ob1.method1()
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case i named my file `helper.scrap.py` and couldn't make it work until i changed to `helper.py`

Comment: I don't think you can have . or - in the file names

Answer (score 1):

in my main script `detectiveROB.py` file i need call `passGen` function which generate password hash and that functions is under `modules\passwordGen.py`

The quickest and easiest solution for me is

**Below is my directory structure**

[image]

So in `detectiveROB.py` i have import my function with below syntax

`from modules.passwordGen import passGen`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick suggestion,
Those who believe in auto-import by pressing alt+ enter in Pycharm and cannot get help.

Just change the file name from where you want to import by:
right-clicking on the file and clicking on refactor-> rename.
Your auto-import option will start coming up