# Import error, No module named xxxx

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project having the structure

```
/example
../prediction
....__init__.py
....a.py
```

PYTHONPATH is pointed to /example

now I open the python in terminal and type

```
import prediction
```

it succeeded, but if I type

```
import prediction.a
```

it returns error

```
ImportError: No module named 'prediction.a'; 'prediction' is not a package
```

why is that? isn't that already imported as a package

Comment: Is there a `prediction.py` file in your working directory that might be taking precedence?  If you `import prediction`, what is `prediction.__file__`?

Comment: @larsks you are right, I have prediction.py there

Comment: @larsks May I suggest you make your comment an answer? It solved my problem, but only came up 4th in Google search results ;)

Comment: I've gone ahead and added an answer.

Comment: Duplicates, yes, but this question and answer are both older and more concise.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing can be caused if there is a module (`foo.py`) or package (`foo/__init__.py`) in your current directory that has a conflicting name.

In your case, I suspect there is a file named `prediction.py`, and you're getting that instead of the `prediction` package in your `examples` directory.

Comment: I've been bagging my head around to workaround a similar issue... this solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: As your answer does only explain the reason but does not present a solution to import a package unambiguously, does that mean that Python is unable to do so?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean.  Python *does not* import files by an absolute pathname, but you are free to modify the module search path yourself to change the order (or locations) in which it searches for things. If you'd like to pursue that question in more detail, you're best is probably opening a new question here on stackoverflow.