# Python imports - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named X

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package, python-3.7

I have read probably all of the posts on here regarding imports and I still cannot figure out what is going on with the imports, I have spent hours trying to get a very simple example working and am literally pulling my hair out.

I am using python 3.7 and pycharm but I am running my code from the commandline, for the unit tests I am using pytest.

My project structure is:

```
my_message_validator/
    __init__.py

    module_1/
        __init.py__
        foo.py

    module_2/
        __init.py__
        bar.py
        baz.py

    module_3
        context.py
        test_all.py
```

module_1.**init**.py

```
from module_1 import foo
```

module_2.**init**.py

```
# For some reason pycharm doesnt complain when I use '.' but if I use module_2 it does
from . import bar, baz
```

If I try to run my code or my tests from the commandline no matter how I move things around I seem to get either `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named`, when I have managed to get the tests working I still cannot run my code on its own from the commandline.

How can I import `module_1` into `module_2` and are these actually packages? I am coming from java and find the imports a lot easier to understand, I am finding the python importing very confusing...

Also how can I can then import whatever I need into my test module\package\folders `context.py`?

Currently the test context look like:

```
import os
import sys

# Is this needed as it doesnt seem to do anything?
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from module_1.foo import Foo

from module_2 import bar, baz
```

In `test_all.py` I am trying to import from the context file like this:

```
from .context import bar,baz
from .context import Foo

# Calling in test like
Foo.load_file(file)

bar.method_one()
baz.method_two()
```

Do I need all the `__init.py__` files and what should I be putting in them to make my methods and classes public\exposed? I would like this entire package to be reusable so want to be able to treat it like a jar file in java.

Any help would be much appreciated as it seems everytime I change something I get an error in a different place, python seems so much more complicated than java right now.

Comment: Have you tried importing like:
from my_message_validator.module_1.foo import Foo
?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, do not use relative imports (with `.`), as it is known for causing [multiple issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209771/7663649). Always write your imports relative to the root of your project. For example, you did it well for `from module_1.foo import Foo`. You should also do it in `test_all.py` and `context.py`. Moreover, after using relative imports, the `__init__.py` files can be left empty in your case.

Most likely, the Python interpreter cannot find your modules because the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable does not contain the root of your project. If you run `export PYTHONPATH="YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT_ABSOLUTE_PATH:$PYTHONPATH"` before your script, it should run as expected. To make sure this variable is set all the time, you can add the export statement to your shell profile file (e.g. `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`).

After chatting with the author, it turns out there was a fourth issue. It was a name collision like the one in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279446/import-error-no-module-named-xxxx). In his project directory, `module_1` was actually called `foo` like its child `foo.py`, which confused the interpreter.

Comment: So would you suggest I get rid of all of the `__init__.py files`? If bar and baz only contain functions and not classes what is the correct way to import them?

Comment: Yes indeed, I suggest you delete all `__init__.py` files. Regarding `bar` and `baz`, you can import functions from them similarly to how you import classes in Java. That is, you can do `from module_2.bar import my_bar_function` and `from module_2.baz import my_baz_function`. Then, you can simply call `my_bar_function()` and `my_baz_function()` in your script.

Comment: And is there any point in using a `context.py` for the tests? I followed a tutorial on how to create packages and it seems to be handling the imports for test suites which then import from `.context`

Comment: It generally depends on how much code is shared between your different tests. I would suggest you start the project without `context.py`, and then add it later in case you find yourself importing the same things all the time across your different tests.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, I have trimmed everything down so that I have no `__init.py__` files and no test context, unfortunately I cannot even import `baz` in `bar` now and my tests fail with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_1'`, I exported the `PYTHONPATH` as you suggested but none of the suggestions has worked.

Comment: `(my_message_validator) validator $ echo $PYTHONPATH
/Users/berimbolo/PycharmProjects/my_message_validator:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202369/discussion-between-pierre-and-berimbolo).

Comment: From [PEP 420 - Implicit Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification): "Regular packages will continue to have an `__init__.py` and will reside in a single directory." Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804718.

Comment: @djvg Thanks for the comment. I agree, and would add that some linters or static analysis tools won't explore directories that are not regular packages. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing like:

```
from my_message_validator.module_1.foo import Foo
from my_message_validator.module_2 import bar, baz
```

Comment: I had thought that using the `__init__.py` files and then exporting there (using import) would mean I wouldnt have to give the full path to everything. What is the norm when developing with python?

Comment: If I would use the absolute path over relative paths do I need to bother with `__init__.py` files at all?

Comment: When I have added the absolute path to my unit test then I get this error instead `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_message_validator'` although pycharm seems to be happy with this format

Comment: absolute path for import is required as Python is recognizing your project path by root directory. Rest of the modules you'll require to mention root onwards.

Comment: `Rest of the modules you'll require to mention root onwards`, could you update your answer with an example please, I dont know what you mean.

Comment: sorry for confusing answer, If my_message_validator is your root path for the project, you need to start importing your modules from my_message_validator. python doesn't recognize your internal modules unless other module is also in the same directory.

Comment: I have given the absolute path and I get this error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`, is there any point in using a relative path or the test context file at all?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case.
I started the application in this way:

```
flask run
```

And every time I got a `ModuleNotFoundError` error on the website.
When I started the application like this:

```
python3 -m flask run
```

the application started without errors :-) .