# Calling and creating a function in python

Tags: python, call

I'm fairly new to python (still in the first few chapters of an introductory book) and i was wondering, once i have defined a function and saved it in script mode, and i want to use it in another script do i have to define it the new program?

To clarify suppose a create a function `multiplybyfive(x)` which takes an input and x and returns 5x. Now suppose i create a program which uses `multiplybyfive(x)` in it, do i have to define it again in this new program or can i simply call it somehow?

Comment: [you can import it](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) look at the docs

Comment: Read this, it should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python

Comment: Thanks, i tried this in the idle mode import multiplybyfive(x) and it came up with an error

Comment: you need a from. `from path/to/file import multiplybyfive` then later you can use it like this. `multiplybyfive(x)`

Comment: @ john Ruddell   do i write it exactly how you have? I tried from path/to/file import multiplybyfive and it returns invalid syntax

Comment: @PavanSangha no. path/to/file is the location of your file. like if its on your desktop for mac then it would be like `/Users/computer_name/Desktop/math_file import multiplybyfive` where computer_name is the name of your computer and math_file is the name of the file that has your math function

Comment: @PavanSangha I would advise you to continue **reading the book**, rather than asking here.

Comment: I saved it in a file called multiply.py and i tried---------------------------------- from multiply import multiplybyfive
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    from multiply import multiplybyfive
ImportError: No module named 'multiply'

Comment: @PavanSangha where is multiply.py saved?

Comment: I have a folder in my desktop of scripts of python programs which i have saved

Comment: ok what is the exact path to your desktop from the root folder?

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean by path

Comment: @PavanSangha your desktop is a folder. it has a parent folder. you have to figure out what your parent folder is until you get to the root folder

Comment: ok, so the path according to your definition is favourites>>>desktop, so i guess the root folder is the favourites folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the python file which contains function multiplybyfive(x) into your new file.

For example, if you write multiplybyfive(x) in file mathfunction.py file.
You can use it in a new program by

```
from mathfunction import multiplybyfive

x = 1
y = multiplybyfive(x)
print y
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I've tried using that in IDLE mode but it doesn't work, does that just work for script mode?

Comment: @PavanSangha you cant just copy paste an import. it has to be a folder path from your computer. look at where the folder is and figure out what your path is

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to define it again? Most languages don't work like this. Consider the following layout:

```
src:
|-- some_module_with_function_def.py
|-- some_other_module_to_call_function.py
```

You can have the function definition in `some_module_with_function_def.py` and you can then use it in `some_other_module_to_call_function.py` just by doing this:

```
from some_module_with_function_def import multiplybyfive

x = multiplybyfive(10)
```