# Python Blackjack - combining two functions

Tags: python, function, blackjack

We are supposed to make a dealer and a player function for blackjack and then combine them into another function. I don't really know how to go about doing that. We also need to include the amount of times the player has won out of the number of games played.

```
import random

def play_hand_player():

    total=0
    player_is_bust=False
    ace_was_thrown=False
    more='y'

    while (more!='n') and not(player_is_bust):
        card=random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10])
        total=total+card

        if (card==1):  #runs if the card is equal to one
            ace_was_thrown=True
            print("Ace\t ",end='')
        else:
            print(card,"\t",end='')

        if (total>21):  #runs if the card total is over 21
            player_is_bust=True
        if not (player_is_bust):
            print("New total: ",end="")
            if (ace_was_thrown) and (total+10<22):
                print(total,"or",total+10,end="")
            else:
                print(total,end="")
            more=input("\tAnother Card? ")        

        if (player_is_bust):
            print("Bust")
        if (more=="n"):
            if (ace_was_thrown==True)and(total+10<17)and(total+10>22):
                print("\tFinal Total: ",total+10)
            else:
                print("\tFinal Total: ",total)

        print("")



def play_hand_dealer():

    total = 0                  
    dealer_is_under = True     
    dealer_is_bust = False     
    ace_was_thrown = False    

    while (dealer_is_under):
        card=random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10])
        total = total + card
        if (card == 1):
            ace_was_thrown = True
            print ("Ace ", end = "")
        else:
            print (card," ", end = "")
        if (total>16):
            dealer_is_under = False
        if (total>21):
            dealer_is_bust = True
        if (ace_was_thrown) and (total + 10 > 16) and (total + 10 < 22):
            dealer_is_under = False
            total = total + 10


    if (dealer_is_bust):
        print (" Bust")
    else:
        print (" Total:", total)

    print ("Instructions: Press Enter Key to play another game, 'q' to quit.\n")

def blackjack():

    gamesWon = 0 
    totalHandsPlayed = 0 
    player = play_hand_player() 
    dealer = play_hand_dealer()

    if player > dealer: 
        gamesWon += 1 
        print ("PLAYER WINS, ")
    else:
        print ("DEALER WINS. ")
```

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python

Comment: I don't see any `return` statements in `play_hand_player` or `play_hand_dealer`, so `player = play_hand_player()` and `dealer = play_hand_dealer()` will just assign `None` to `player ` and `dealer`.