# 'module' object is not callable when calling another function defined in the same folder

Tags: python, function, call

I was referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python) to call a Python function from another Python file.

So I have 2 Python scripts in the same folder: `myFunc.py` and `caller.py`.

First, I defined a simple function in `myFunc.py` as following:

```
def mySqrt(x):
    return x**2
```

...then I tried to use this function in my `caller.py`, like this:

```
import myFunc as mySqrt

a = mySqrt(2)
print(a)
```

...but it returns:

> 'module' object is not callable

...when the script `caller.py` is executed.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: `from myFunc import mySqrt` -- try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving an alias to your import that has the same name as the function you want to call. Try:

```
from myFunc import mySqrt
```

Or if you want to keep the same formatting, try:

```
import myFunc as mf

a = mf.mySqrt(2)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### What you have:

```
import myFunc as mySqrt
```

imports the module and gives it a different name.

#### You want:

```
from myFunc import mySqrt
```

Answer (score 2):

As the question you mentioned states use:

```
from myFunc import mySqrt
```

`as` is used to create `alias` to the module, so you could shorten the typing, like in the following example:

```
from myFunc import mySqrt as ms
a = ms(2)
print(a)
#4
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Here's what you should have:

```
from myFunc import mySqrt
```

#### Explanation:

- **`import <module> as <module_alias>`**

**This instruction imports `<module>` under the name `<module_alias>`.**

So `import myFunc as mySqrt` would import the module `myFunc` under the name `mySqrt`, which is not what you want!

- **`from <module> import <function>`**

**This instruction imports `<function>` from `<module>`.**

So `from myFunc import mySqrt` would import the function `mySqrt()` from your module `myFunc`, which is the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Very nice.