# How to call functions from another file in python

Tags: python, function, class

I am not too far into python yet and here is the case.

Say I have one python file called functions.py which holds a class with my functions. Below is an example.

```
import json

class Functionalities:
    def addelement(element):
        # code goes here`
```

And I have another python file, kind of 'executable' script which does all the job using functions from functions.py class

Adding `from . import functions` doesn't help.

How to I call functions from the class from another file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call a function from another file in Python
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python)

Comment: Don't randomly put functions into classes. There is no need to do so unless you're storing state to be passed between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike java, you don't have to use classes in python. If a class is used only as a holder for functions, chances are that you want a free function (one without a class) instead.

But to answer your actual question, you can use the `import` statement. That will run the other .py file, and make the namespace available so you can call things defined there.

`functions.py`:

```
import json

class Functionalities:
    def addelement(element):
        # code goes here`
```

`main.py`:

```
import functions
f = functions.Functionalities()
f.addelement('some element')
```

Comment: I just thought i'd better sort functions into different classes (or we can say categories in my case) so not to make a mess in future when there will be a lot of functions in one file.
But thanks for the answer and suggestion. It worked!

Comment: @MherHarutyunyan the pythonic way to sort functions in python is to use modules... not classes.