# Use a function from one script in another

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have a function that connects to a database thats predefined. The code looks like:
**file1.py**

```
def conn_db():
    try:
        cursor = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        conn = pymysql.connect(host=settings.host,
                                user=settings.user,
                                password=settings.password,
                                db=settings.database,
                                port=settings.port,
                                cursorclass=cursor)
        dbcursor = conn.cursor()
    except pymysql.err.OperationalError as e:
        print("Unable to make a connection to the mysql database. \n Error was:{}".format(e))

    return conn, dbcursor
```

How can I use this function `conn_db` from `file1.py` in file2.py. And then call file2.py from executing python's intrepreter via `python` ?

Having a hard time even identifying something so basic, after several attempts.

Thank you.

Comment: In file2.py: `from file1 import *` and then call your function

Comment: You seem to be looking for the `import` statement. E.g. `from file1 import conn_db`

Comment: John, please google your questions before asking them here. A simple "call function from another file python" in google search would've yielded you the answer. This question might get downvoted and closed soon. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `import file1` and then use `file1.conn_db()` to use the function.