# Importing functions from another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

my_main_file.py:

```
from bfile import bfunc
def fna():
  bfunc(sth)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  fna()
```

bfile.py:

```
def bfunc(sth):
  #bla bla..
```

Error:

> name 'bfunc' is not defined

Both files are under same directory

PS:
I have tried everythig here [Call a function from another file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python)

Comment: where that `sth` come from ?

Comment: Are you running in that directory? Is `.` in your PYTHONPATH, or alternatively in `sys.path`?

Comment: created within funa()

Comment: sys.path doesn't contain current directory, PYTHONPATH is blank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 1):

Add `__init__.py` python file to your current working directory.So python will treat directory as containing package.You can see documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import bfile
def fna():
    bfile.bfunc(sth)
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `export PYTHONPATH="."`
to `bash_profile` solved the issue