# How can I call a function which I have defined in a file in another file?

Tags: python-3.x, user-defined-functions

Let assume I have a function called my_func defined in a file called my_file.ipynb.

I want to call that function in another file called test.ipynb. How can I do that?

Comment: This 2 question my help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path/67692#67692

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html