# Attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

```
from ..box_utils import decode, nms
```

This line is giving **error**

> ImportError: *attempted relative import with no known parent package*

What is this error and how to resolve this error?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of python are you using (specifically, not just 3.x)?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Apparently, `box_utils.py` isn't part of a package. You still can import functions defined in this file, but only if the python script that tries to import these functions lives in the same directory as `box_utils.py`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20309470/7069126).

Nota bene: In my case, I stumbled upon this error with an import statement with one period, like this:
`from .foo import foo`. This syntax, however, tells Python that `foo.py` is part of a package, which wasn't the case. The error disappeared when I removed the period.

Comment: how to make it part of a package?

Comment: put a file called `__init.py__` in the same directory

Comment: I did add __ init __.py

Comment: This worked for me. Just remove the . in front of foo in `from .foo import foo`

Comment: The comment from @RagavY worked for me - i.e. just remove the "." in front of the path

Answer (score 22):

If a different dictionary contains `script.py`, it can be accessed from the root. For instance:

If your program is structured...:

```
/alpha
  /beta
    /delta
  /gamma
    /epsilon
      script.py
    /zeta
```

...then a script in the `epsilon` directory can be called by:

`from alpha.gamma.epsilon import script`

Comment: But what if you want to import a file, w/o referencing the root package? Eg, what if one wanted to import `gamma/epsilon.py` from `delta` with a relative reference (ie, not referring to `alpha`)

Comment: @svangordon That would also interest me. Or in other words, beta is a package and gamma is another package. But they are not two subpackages of alpha. How to handle this?

Comment: @svangordon: I guess I figured it out. If both of them are packages (i.e., there are _ _ init _ _ .py files in beta and gamma, but not in alpha), go in the alpha directory and type: `pip install -e .`. I have not tried when two packages are in that directory, but at least if there is only one package in the directory and you do that, you can in another Python file type `import beta` or `import beta.delta`

Comment: If you have a module in `delta` called `script.py` (alpha > beta > delta > script.py) and want to call the `epsilon` module (alpha > gamma > epsilon.py), you can import it using `from ...gamma import epsilon`. NOTE that if you want to run this as a script, `python -m alpha/beta/delta/script.py` will NOT work! You need to call it using `python -m alpha.beta.delta.script` instead.

Comment: This was pretty confusing and I needed to play around with this a bit until I understaood this, so uploaded some example code to https://github.com/slow-but-steady/relative-imports-in-python for anyone who wants to play around with this more.

Answer (score -2):

in the latest python version, import it, directly don't use .. and .library
import the file which you want. this technique will work in the child directory.
If you import it from parent directory, then place the directory's full path.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your answer with code explanations and improved formatting. It will help others understand.

Answer (score -10):

```
package
   |--__init__.py
   |--foo.py
   |--bar.py
```

Content of `bar.py`

```
from .foo import func
...
```

If someone is getting the exactly same error for `from .foo import func`.

It's because you've forgot to make it a package. So you just need to create `__init__.py` inside `package` directory.

Comment: the error still exist even when __init__.py exist in `package` directory

Comment: make sure it's exactly `__init__.py`

Comment: The `__init__.py` file makes no difference (I think it's no longer required as of Python 3.3). This isn't working for me either (with or without `__init__.py`), and I've got no idea why.