# Importing module in pre-commit hook requires runtime path addition

Tags: python, git, import, module

I want to import and test a module in a pre-commit hook in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`. The structure is:

```
set_prefix.py
temp.py
.git
  |----hooks
         |----pre-commit
```

The file `set_prefix.py` could simply be:

```py
def main():
    pass
```

The file `temp.py` is:

```py
import set_prefix
```

Calling `python3 temp.py` throws no error.

For `.git/hooks/pre-commit`, I confirmed with `import os; print(os.getcwd())` that the working directory is the same as `set_prefix.py`.

The following imports fail:

- `import set_prefix` fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'set_prefix'`
- `from . import set_prefix` fails with `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` (probably because [it's not part of a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084977/attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)).

One import that works, from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above) requires adding to the path at runtime:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(".") # Adds current directory to python modules path.
from . import set_prefix
```

Why does importing behave differently between a file on the same directory and the pre-commit hook if they both have the same current directory at runtime?

### Update

Another solution, mentioned in the comments, is to turn the directory into a package with an `__init__.py` file. But I still don't understand why the import works from `temp.py` and not from the pre-commit hook if they both run from the same directory.

Comment: @napuzba I read the tutorial. I still don't understand why the import works from `temp.py` and not from the pre-commit hook if they both run from the same directory, and I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-commit hook creates an env where it only has the changed files (the ones after filtering through the regex of `files` option) to make the pre-commit check fast.
The `set_prefix.py` file that you mentioned, needs to have changes for it to be added to the pre-commit env. Therefore the file is not found while running pre-commit hooks but it works when the test is run normally.

One solution would be to also pass the `set_prefix.py` file to the arguments in the pre-commit hook (If it is pylint or another linter)

Comment: Thanks! I no longer use pre-commit hooks, but if anyone else is trying this and confirms that it woks, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue, that's how I came upon this. Found the answer through trial and error and using it now. Though I can't say for sure about the internal workings of the hook, I think this is a rare issue