# Python - ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import, importerror

I have a trouble with imports in my project.

My directories structure is the following:

```
base_directory
  - examples
  - src
    - folder_1
      - __init__.py
      - file.py
    - folder_2
      - __init__.py
      - class1.py
      - class2.py
      - class3.py
      - class4.py
```

In `file.py` I'm trying: `from ..folder2.class1 import Class1` then, I get the error:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

In `folder2/__init__.py` I did what I saw on a tutorial for making packages in Python:

```
from class1 import Class1

my_class_1 = Class1()
```

So far, anything has worked. What should I do? I use Python 3.7.5

Thanks.

Comment: try this once `from .class1 import Class1`

Comment: Oddly enough, although it shouldn't, I seem to be able to [get it to work](https://repl.it/@EnochKumala/CautiousWeirdScriptinglanguages#src/folder_1/file.py) without any errors, but the answer is correct

Comment: what you propose @AbhishekChatterjee it does not work, it seems like the only way to make this works is putting all the files in `base_directory`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attempted relative import with no known parent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084977/attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)

Answer (score 4):

In your example, folder_1 and folder_2 are two separate and unique packages. There are no relative imports between them. Put them in a single outer package to get it to work

```
base_directory
  - examples
  - src
      - mypackage
        - __init__.py
        - folder_1
          - __init__.py
          - file.py
                print("imported", __file__)
                from ..folder_2.class1 import Class1
                print("file.py found", Class1)
        - folder_2   
          - __init__.py
          - class1.py
                print("imported", __file__)
                class Class1:
                def __init__(self):
                    print("Created Class1 instance")
          - class2.py
          - class3.py 
          - class4.py
      - test.py
            import myproject.folder_1.file
```

Running test.py script

```
~/tmp/base_directory/src$ python test.py
imported /home/td/tmp/base_directory/src/myproject/folder_1/file.py
imported /home/td/tmp/base_directory/src/myproject/folder_2/class1.py
file.py found <class 'myproject.folder_2.class1.Class1'>
```

But there is a workaround where modules can be called using the "-m" option. But his only works if `myproject` is in the python path. It works here because I'm in the parent of myproject when I call it.

```
~/tmp/base_directory/src$ python -m myproject.folder_1.file
imported /home/td/tmp/base_directory/src/myproject/folder_1/file.py
imported /home/td/tmp/base_directory/src/myproject/folder_2/class1.py
file.py found <class 'myproject.folder_2.class1.Class1'>
```

Comment: Yes this is correct. A file under ‘src’ but above the two sub-packages is needed to call the main function in file.py or whatever file holds the main function of how the program starts and runs.

Comment: Are you running `file.py` as a script or importing it as a module? Scripts aren't in packages so relative imports don't work. I'll update the example with some code to demonstrate.

Comment: @Francisco , maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886769/is-it-possible-to-import-a-python-file-from-outside-the-directory-the-main-file could solve your problem?