# Import a Python file from different directory in Terminal and Jupyter

Tags: python, python-import

I have a package structured like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and contained within a folder.

```py
project
├── jupyter.ipynb
└── package
    ├── __init__.py (from . import app1, app2)
    ├── app1
    │   ├── __init__.py (from . import foo)
    │   └── foo.py
    └── app2
        ├── __init__.py (from . import bar)
        └── bar.py
```

What I want to do is import `bar.py` into `foo.py`, and for this I add the following in `foo.py`:

```py
from ..app2 import bar
```

Now, from the `jupyter.ipynb` file the libraries are successfully imported as follows:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, './')
from package import app1, app2
```

However, in the terminal, inside the project folder, the following command throws the error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

```bash
cd project
python package/app1/foo.py
```

What am I missing? I have also tried absolute imports (e.g., `from package.app2.bar import func()` or `from app2.bar import func()`) but they don't work. I have also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886769/is-it-possible-to-import-a-python-file-from-outside-the-directory-the-main-file) posts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not following the rationale for `python package/app1/foo.py`? Just before that you post you are running Python in Jupyter and you import into the namespace of the running Python session. That makes sense. So the equivalent in Python would be to type `python` in the terminal to bring up the Python interpreter, use Python to change the working directory,  and then run those three lines you ran the equivalent of the three line you ran in Jupyter. Then if that works, you can move that code and the subsequent steps into a script and run it in the terminal with `python my_script.py`.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Wayne! Just to clarify, `my_script.py` contains the same import procedure mentioned for the `jupyter.ipynb`file,  and should be located outside the package folder (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?rq=2), very helpful).

Comment: So you sorted it out now and it works in Python in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, @Wayne. When I want to deploy the code from the terminal I followed your suggestion: in `foo.py` I added the line `from ..app2 import bar` and in a Python file outside the package folder I added the same lines from the jupyter.ipynb file; running this file from the terminal works perfectly. Another way to do it, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?rq=2), is to run from the terminal `python -m package.app1.foo`; it also works perfectly.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/7247064)?

Comment: Yes, @JamieNguyen. That answer was also very helpful and clear, thanks for sharing it too!