# Import error when using torch.utils.bottleneck

Tags: python, pytorch

I use `torch.utils.bottleneck` to profile the code.

But I got some import errors as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "./benchmark/csm/gnn.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ...data import sc as snc
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How can I use 'torch.utils.bottleneck' to profile my code without modifying my project code?

Because there are a lot of `from ...xx import xx as xx` in my project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attempted relative import with no known parent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084977/attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved this by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20309470/7394312)