# I CANT IMPORT THE VIEWS MODULE FOR DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting to work with Django in python, and whenever I try to import the views module I get this import error :

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: This assumes that there is a `views` module available to import, which we have no evidence of

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084977/attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attempted relative import with no known parent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084977/attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)

Comment: `from .app_name import func_name` Please import like this syntax. Here we assume app_name is 'my_app' and function name is 'home' then:
`import .my_app import home'

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: Here `app_name` is name of the app you written `home` function.

```
from django.urls import path
from .app_name import home
urlpatterns = [
    path('',home, name='home'),
]
```

**Function views**

1. Add an import:`from my_app import views`
2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:`path('', views.home, name='home')`

**Class-based views**
3. Add an import:  `from other_app.views import Home`
4. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  `path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')`

**Including another URLconf**
5. Import the include() function: `from django.urls import include,` path
6. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  `path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))`

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/

Comment: I tried it but it did not work so I tried something similar which is: I importer the home function from the views module  ( file)  and the error is gone,  but I still get a problem that says : " No name 'home' in module views"

Comment: Are you written `urls.py` in your new app or main `urls.py` ??

Comment: what is your app name ??

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app_name.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",home),
]
```

Try doing this.
app_name indicates your app name.