# Can't manage to use correctly a library - Errors on import or on function not recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-import, importerror

From [pybss](https://github.com/archimonde1308/pybss), I can't execute a simple using of the function ffdiag, which is by the way defined in my script `bss.py` :

```
from numpy import dot,diag,eye,zeros
from numpy.linalg import svd,pinv,multi_dot,norm,inv,cholesky
from scipy.linalg import expm

# remove later
import numpy as np

from . import linalg

# dimension
m=7
# number of matrices
n=2

# Load spectro and WL+GCph+XC
FISH_GCsp = np.loadtxt('Fisher_GCsp_flat.txt')
FISH_XC = np.loadtxt('Fisher_XC_GCph_WL_flat.txt')

# Marginalizing over uncommon parameters between the two matrices
COV_GCsp_first = np.linalg.inv(FISH_GCsp)
COV_XC_first = np.linalg.inv(FISH_XC)
COV_GCsp = COV_GCsp_first[0:m,0:m]
COV_XC = COV_XC_first[0:m,0:m]
# Invert to get Fisher matrix
FISH_sp = np.linalg.inv(COV_GCsp)
FISH_xc = np.linalg.inv(COV_XC)
# Drawing a random set of commuting matrices
C=np.zeros((n,m,m));
B=np.zeros((m,m));
C[0] = np.array(FISH_sp)
C[1] = np.array(FISH_xc)

# Perform operation of diagonalisation
invV, B, ut = ffdiag(C, 10, 1.0e-10, 100)

#print(B)

# Print diagonal matrices
M0 = np.dot(np.dot(B,C[0]),B.T)
M1 = np.dot(np.dot(B,C[1]),B.T)
print(M0)
print('')
print(M1)

FISH_final = M0 + M1

def ffdiag_update(R_tau,ortho):
    '''
    Single update for the non-orthogonal FFDIAG algorithm.  Set ortho = True to
    do the proper update for the orthogonal version of the algorithm.
    '''
    Dk = {}
    Ek = {}
    dim = len(R_tau[0])
    n_lags = len(R_tau.keys())
    for tau in R_tau.keys():
        Dk[tau] = diag(diag(R_tau[tau]))
        Ek[tau] = R_tau[tau] - Dk[tau]
    W = zeros((dim,dim))
    if ortho is False:
        z = zeros(W.shape)
        y = zeros(W.shape)
        for i in range(0,dim):
            for j in range(0,dim):
                for tau in range(0,n_lags):
                    z[i,j] += Dk[tau][i,i]*Dk[tau][j,j]
                    y[i,j] += Dk[tau][j,j]*Ek[tau][i,j]
        # compute W
        for i in range(0,dim):
            for j in range(i+1,dim):
                W[i][j] = (z[i,j]*y[j,i]-z[i,i]*y[i,j])/(z[j,j]*z[i,i]-z[i,j]*z[i,j])
                W[j][i] = (z[i,j]*y[i,j]-z[j,j]*y[j,i])/(z[j,j]*z[i,i]-z[i,j]*z[i,j])
    else:
        num = zeros((dim,dim))
        den = zeros((dim,dim))
        for i in range(0,dim):
            for j in range(i+1,dim):
                for tau in range(0,n_lags):
                    num[i,j] +=  Ek[tau][i,j]*(Dk[tau][i,i] - Dk[tau][j,j])
                    den[i,j] += (Dk[tau][i,i]-Dk[tau][j,j])**2
                if i != j:
                    W[i,j] = num[i,j]/den[i,j]
                    # W must be skew-symmetric (W = -W^T)
                    W[j,i] = -W[i,j]
    return W



def amuse(X, tau = 1):
    '''
    Runs the AMUSE algorithm on the signal matrix X; extracts a full
    set of X.shape[0] sources

    INPUT:
    ------
    X : array, required
        N_sig x t matrix of signal mixtures

    tau : integer, optional
        sets the lag used for cross-correlation matrix
        computation

    OUTPUT:
    ------
    A : array
        n_sig x n_sig mixing matrix

    W : array
        n_sig x n_sig unmixing matrix

    S : array
        n_sig x t array of extracted sources
    '''

    Rx = dot(X,X.T)
    ux,sx,vx = svd(Rx, full_matrices = False)
    psi = sx**0.5
    C = diag(1/psi)
    Y = dot(C,X)
    t = X.shape[1]

    Ry = linalg.lagged_covariance(Y,tau)[tau]

    uy,sy,vy = svd((Ry + Ry.T)/2, full_matrices=False)

    S = dot(vy.T,Y)
    A = dot(dot(uy, diag(psi)), vy)
    W = pinv(A)

    return A,W,S


def sobi(X, max_lag = 15):
    '''
    Blind source separation using SOBI (second-order blind identification)
    algorithm.

    INPUT:
    ------
    X : array, required
        N_sig x t matrix of signal mixtures

    max_lag : int, optional
        maximum lag (in samples) for covariance matrix calculation
    '''
    Kw,Kd = linalg.whitening_matrix(X, len(X[:,0]))
    Z = dot(Kw,X)
    R_tau = linalg.lagged_covariance(Z,max_lag)
    D = linalg.joint_diagonalizer(R_tau)
    S  = dot(D.T,Z)
    A = dot(Kd,D)
    W = dot(D.T,Kw)
    return A,W,S


def ffdiag(X, max_lag = 10, eps = 1.0e-10, max_iter = 100):
    '''
    Blind source separation using FFDIAG.  This version does not require that
    the estimated mixing matrix be orthogonal.

    INPUT:
    ------
    X : array, required
        N_sig x t matrix of signal mixtures

    max_lag : int, optional
        maximum lag (in samples) for covariance matrix calculation

    eps : double, optional
        convergence criterion for matrix updates

    max_iter : int, optional
        maximum number of iterations/updates
    '''
    R_tau = linalg.lagged_covariance(X,max_lag)
    dim = len(R_tau[0])
    n_lags = len(R_tau.keys())
    W = zeros((dim,dim))
    V = eye(dim)
    C = R_tau
    niter = 0
    theta = 0.9
    iter_eps = 1.0

    while iter_eps > eps and niter < max_iter:
        niter += 1
        Vn1 = V

        for tau in range(0,n_lags):
            C[tau] = multi_dot([eye(dim) + W,C[tau],(eye(dim)+W).T])

        # update term
        W = ffdiag_update(C,False)
        if norm(W) > theta:
            W = (W*theta)/norm(W)

        # update V
        V = dot(eye(dim) + W,V)

        delta = 0
        for i in range(0,dim):
            for j in range(0,dim):
                if i == j:
                    pass
                else:
                    delta += (V[i][j]-Vn1[i][j])**2
        iter_eps = (delta/(dim*(dim-1)))

    ut = dot(V,X)
    return inv(V),V, ut


def ortho_ffdiag(X, max_lag = 10, eps = 1.0e-08, max_iter = 100):
    '''
    Blind source separation using FFDIAG.  This version (like SOBI, AMUSE, etc.)
    finds an orthogonal mixing matrix.

    INPUT:
    ------
    X : array, required
        N_sig x t matrix of signal mixtures

    max_lag : int, optional
        maximum lag (in samples) for covariance matrix calculation

    eps : double, optional
        convergence criterion for matrix updates

    max_iter : int, optional
        maximum number of iterations/updates
    '''
    R_tau = linalg.lagged_covariance(X,max_lag)
    dim = len(R_tau[0]) # formerly N
    n_lags = len(R_tau.keys()) # formerly K
    W = zeros((dim,dim))
    V = eye(dim)
    C = R_tau
    n_iter = 0
    theta = 0.9
    iter_eps = 1.0

    while iter_eps > eps and n_iter < max_iter:
        n_iter += 1
        Vn1 = V
        for tau in range(0,n_lags):
            C[tau] = multi_dot([eye(dim) + W,C[tau],(eye(dim)+W).T])
        W = ffdiag_update(C,True)
        if norm(W) > theta:
            W = (W*theta)/norm(W)
        # update V
        V = dot(expm(W),V)
        delta = 0
        for i in range(0,dim):
            for j in range(0,dim):
                if i != j:
                    delta += (V[i][j]-Vn1[i][j])**2
        eps = (delta/(dim*(dim-1)))

    ut = dot(V,X)
    return inv(V),V, ut


def fobi(X):
    '''
    Blind source separation via the FOBI (fourth order blind identification)
    algorithm.
    '''
    R_x = linalg.lagged_covariance(X,0)
    C = cholesky(R_x[0])
    Y = dot(inv(C),X)

    R_y = (norm(Y)**2)*(dot(Y,Y.T))
    u,s,Y_i = svd(R_y)

    alpha = dot(Y_i,Y)   # messages (extracted sources)
    X_i = dot(C,Y_i)     # signatures (mixing matrix)
    W_i = pinv(X_i)      # unmixing matrix
    # return things in A,W,S order to conform to other bss methods
    return X_i,W_i,alpha
```

1. But I get a common error that I can't manage to fix :

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "bss.py", line 8, in 
   from . import linalg
   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

You can see the browsing on this image :

[image: sructure of library]

2. I have also to put :

   `from linalg import linalg` instead of but problem remains.
3. Another thing to do is to put :

   from linalg import *

In this case, I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bss.py", line 36, in <module>
    invV, B, ut = ffdiag(C, 10, 1.0e-10, 100)
NameError: name 'ffdiag' is not defined
```

Is there a link between this error message and the line "`from linalg import *`"

Comment: It looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55084977/4611565) question.

Comment: Usually we do `import numpy as np` and use `np.array`, `np.dot` and `np.linalg.expm`.  Most of numpy is available this way.

Comment: you are getting the last `NameError` because you are trying to use `ffdiag` before you define it, move the function definition higher in the code