# Can't import my module functions into notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Apologies for yet another "why can't I import my python function" question. I'm not happy about it either.

I have a python project with the following structure:

```
 ~/my-repo  tree my_package
my_package
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── utils.py
├── notebooks
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── notebook.ipynb
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── integration_test.py
│   └── unit_tests.py
```

`utils.py` contains the following import and function:

```
import pandas as pd

def util_func():
    ts = pd.Timestamp.now()
    return ts
```

I can successfully import `util_func` in `main.py` and in `unit_tests.py`. I can also successfully run `main.py` from the shell, and run `pytest` from the shell (from `my-repo`) which successfully imports `util_func` to test it.

But in `my-repo/notebooks/notebook.ipynb`, I cannot import `util_func` from `utils.py`. I know in the notebook, my package is not installed, so presumably I need some sort of relative import for it, but I can't get it to work. Some things I have tried:

- `from ..utils import util_func`
- `from ..my_repo.utils import util_func`
- `from utils import util_func`
- adding the `__init__.py` file to the `notebooks/` directory per many SO answers to similar questions
- moving `notebooks/` folder from `my-repo/my_package/notebooks/` up to `my-repo/notebooks/`
- read answers to [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55084977/1870832) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/1870832) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/1870832) and others
- (UPDATE) adding `from sys import path` & `path.append("../")`

When I type `from ..utils import util_func`, my IDE even auto-completes and the colors of `utils` and `util_func` indicate they're found. But then when I execute the cell I always get either `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` or `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I don't want to move the `notebook.ipynb` into the top-level `my-repo/` directory because overtime we will spawn more and more exploratory notebooks and I don't want them cluttering the top-level directory, but I need to be able to import our util functions running notebooks interactively.

What do I need to change, in either `notebook.ipynb` or my package/folder structure, to allow me to import `util_func` from `utils.py` in my notebook (and without breaking my ability to run `python -m my_package.main` and `pytest` successfully from `$my-repo/`)

Answer (score 0):

You must set relative path
in order to do that

```
from sys import path
path.append("../")
```

This will set path to parent directory
now

```
from utils import util_func
```

Now module will be sucessully imported

Comment: thanks for the suggestion  but this did not work for me. after your sys/path code, `from utils import util_func` throws `ModuleNotFoundError`, and `from ..my_package.utils import util_func` throws `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`