# How to call a python routine from another python routine?

Tags: python, python-3.x

html is just text, often very repetitive. I have a simple homework webpage. I'm trying to automate the webpage production.

I have Python routines for producing html (I made them, so they are primitive, but they all work):

```
makeCheckboxes.py  
makeDropdownboxes.py  
makehtmlTable.py  
makeRadiobuttons.py  
makeTextboxes.py  
makeThankyouPHP.py
```

and lastly:

```
makeWebpage.py
```

They all just output a text file.

Rather than lump all these in one very big, long file (I lose the plot easily), I'd like to call the one or ones I want from makeWebpage.py and run it, then knot the sections together into 1 text file.

They are all in /home/pedro/textTohtml/ I run them in a bash terminal.

I don't need all the routines each week.
All I need to know is, how many sections I want and what's in it.

For example, let's say next week: Section 1 is radio buttons, Section 2 is Textboxes (fill in the gaps exercise)

Can I call the 2 routines from makeWebpage.py without actually defining them within as functions?

The functions themselves produce a text file which I can then open and integrate into the webpage template.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. What I need is to import the whole file, each of which will then have its own inner functions.
If I do this:

```
import file as fl
```

Will it then run fl?
Or is it better to run subprocess?

Comment: Note, python has functions, generally the terminology routine is not used  What you have here are *modules.* Depending upon  how you've organized them, i.e. by populating them with re-usavle functions, you can use code written in modules wherever you want.

Comment: If you are going to be reusing code, you will need to define some functions, even if you keep those functions is a separate file. Technically, you can run each file's code using `subprocess` but what you really should do is wrap the code in `def`s and use `import`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this help you:

[Call a function from another file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20309470/8250558)

You just need to use

```
from file import function
```

To import the functions at the start of your makeWebpage.py file. Then makeWebpage.py can call any of the functions any time it wants.

Comment: Woohoo! I managed to import makeRBsV1 and it worked like a dream! Thanks for the link! Apparently I don't need to write .py

Comment: A problem: I do 'import makeRBsInlineV1 as fl' and my program runs perfectly. BUT it starts straight away. I can't assign it to a string variable. I need to assign the output to a string variable. I modified the python, put return htmlString at the end. How can I assign the output to say myString?? This just gives an error:>>> string = import makeRBsInlineV1 as fl
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: try:
htmlValue = yourMethodName()

Comment: Yesterday I had trouble with this, but I am a morning person. This morning at 5am I figured it out very quickly! Got all my modules imported into makeWebpage.py! Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a function:

```
from FILE import FUNCTION
FUNCTION(*args,**kwargs)
```

If you want to run/execute the python file (everything):

```
import os
os.system("FILE")
```

[NOTE] The file must be a string and contain the extension, eg `"some_file.py"` whereas in import statements only the file name is specified in plaintext.

In both cases both files must be in the same directory unless a path is specified (`"c:\Users\MyProfile\PythonFiles\python.py"` or `"/Users/MyProfile/PythonFiles\python.py"`)

EDIT: If you are importing an entire file (STRICTLY LIKE THIS!) `from FILE import *` you can name variables or functions with an underscore before it to prevent it from being imported (more info on PEP 8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36)

Comment: I tried with import makeRBsV1 as fl that worked OK!