# Trying simple import in python

Tags: python

I am trying the first example from
[here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

But for some reason I get the message:
Microsoft Visual Studio
The project cannot be launched because of the startup file 
'C:\Users\itay8\source\repos\fibo\module1.py was not found.

the 'fibo.py' file and the 'import_from.py' that I am trying to import to are in the same folder.

the version of python that I am using is 3.80

the code in fibo.py file:

## Fibonacci numbers module

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()
```

the code in import_from_fibo.py:

```
import fibo
fibo.fib(10)
```

now to the current problem is that it can't find the function. the output:
Exception unhandled module 'fibo' has no attribute 'fib'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a function from another file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python)

Comment: Can you please edit this post to include the full, current contents of both files? Also, please note the version of Python you are using (try `py --version`).

Comment: Are you totally sure that the files are in the same directory? Check using Explorer or the `dir` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Visual Studio, try using the command line Python interpreter for your early practice. You can go back to Visual Studio later when you start a bigger project, but for now, it should work to just type:

```
> cd <wherever your project is>
> py import_from_fibo.py
```

This should run the contents of `import_from_fibo.py`.

I also note that its current contents do not call the function `fib`; try adding

```py
print(fibo.fib(5))
```

or so to the bottom of `import_from_fibo.py`.

Comment: C:\Users\itay8\source\repos\fibo>py import_from_fibo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_from_fibo.py", line 2, in <module>
    fibo.fib(10)
NameError: name 'fibo' is not defined.                 
  I tried that :\. any idea why it cant find the fibo file?

Comment: Have you ensured that `import_from_fibo.py` file contains both the import and the call? I tried to recreate your situation, but it appears to work for me...

Comment: they are in the same solution so I think so.

Comment: Use `dir` or File Explorer to make absolutely sure the two are in the same directory, and that both have the filenames you expect. I would recommend not using Visual Studio for this until you're more well-versed in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a module does not make its content directly accessible.

When you type `import fibo`, you just tell Python that you will use it later. To access the `fib` function you have at least two possibilities:

1. Open the module, and access `fib`:

```py
import fibo

fibo.fib(3)
```

2. Import only `fib` and use it directly:

```py
from fibo import fib

fib(3)
```

You can find more details on the page you linked https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score -1):

add an empty file naming `__init__.py` to make it a module.