# Call a python script from a python script within the same context

Tags: python, pycharm

There is a python script `start_test.py`.

There is a second python script `siple_test.py`.

```
# pseudo code:
start_test.py --calls--> subprocess(python.exe simple_test.py, args_simple_test[])
```

The python interpreter for both scripts is the same. So instead of opening a new instance, I want to run `simple_test.py` directly from `start_test.py`. I need to preserve the sys.args environment. A *nice to have* would be to actually enter following code section in `simple_test.py`:

```
# file: simple_test.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_test_function()
```

Most important is, that the way should be a universal one, not depending on the content of the `simple_test.py`.

*This setup would provide two benefits:*

1. The call is much less resource intensive
2. The whole stack of `simple_test.py` can be debugged with pycharm

**So, how do I execute the call of a python script, from a python script, without starting a new subprocess?**

Comment: You could import the function like this: `from file import function` see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python

Comment: thx, but how do I preserve the individual context of the subprocess args? Just like sys.args = ['my', 'awesome','test','args']. Or is there a more pythonc way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

"Executing a script" is a somewhat blurry term.

Typically the `if __name__== "__main__":` part does the argument (`sys.argv`) decoding and then calls a worker function with explicit parameters. For clarity: It should not do anything else, since this additional work can't be called without creating a new process causing all the overhead you are trying to avoid.

You simply bypass that and call this implementing routine directly.

So you end up with start_test.py containing something like:

```
from simple_test import worker
# ...
worker(typed_arg1, typed_arg2)
```