# How call a python script from a python process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  have to call a long run process from a bottle script (web framework like Django).

So in a bottle script i have

```
os.system("python /home/tom/Documents/proc_test/main.py")
```

Anyway the main.py script is not executed.
How can i call a python script from another running python program?

P.S: in python shell interpreter i have write os.system("python /home/tom/Documents/proc_test/main.py") and the file is called

Comment: It's python. Import it and call the function.

Comment: Did you try to `exec` it ? `exec(open("/home/tom/Documents/proc_test/main.py").read())`
It will work only if the file is executable though.
Not related, but I prefer to use the `subprocess` module to execute binaries.

Comment: @Frodon could you avoid suggesting the worse possible solution ?

Comment: "the main.py script is not executed" => then you may want to find out why. "How can i call a python script from another running python program?" => just like for any other executable - using `os.system` or `subprocess`. But unless you have a compelling reason to run it as a distinct process, you should probably just import the script as a module and call it's entry point (assuming it's correctly written so it can be used that way).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a python script from a python script within the same context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355847/call-a-python-script-from-a-python-script-within-the-same-context)

Answer (score 0):

Like Dirk suggested, import the main.py from python then call the function.

Or if you need to actually run main.py as a separate process then use `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python /home/tom/Documents/proc_test/main.py"])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How is this different from `os.system` ?

Comment: os.system() executes the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same limitations. Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in the environment of the executed command. If command generates any output, it will be sent to the interpreter standard output stream.

On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return value of the Python function is system-dependent.

Comment: The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using os.system()

Comment: I meant: Why should `python /home/tom/Documents/proc_test/main.py`run via subprocess if it does not via os.system() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the python script directly via full path using [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib).
Lets assume this example main.py:

```
def func():
    print("func called")
```

In your main script, you import as follows:

```
import importlib as imp
spec = imp.util.spec_from_file_location('d', '/home/tom/Documents/proc_test/main.py')
foo = imp.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)

foo.func()
```

Output:

```
func called
```