# How to import a pandas dataframe from a python file to another python file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-import

I have two python files in the same folder: main.py and analysis.py.

In the analysis.py file I have a pandas dataframe called `df1`, inside a class called Ana(path, file)

I have imported the class to main.py successfully by writing `from analysis import Ana`, but if I try to do something with df1 it says *df1 is not defined*.

How do I define df1 in the main.py file? I am quite new to Python so any help will be very appreciated, thank you.

P.S. I forgot to add, I am trying to use the df1 from the Ana function in the analysis.py file in the function Upload in the main.py file

Comment: Andrew try to use functions to return where lives the dataframe then import the function in second file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20309470/8807216

Answer (score 1):

Do a function returning Ana. If it's a member:

```
def ret_Ana():
    return self.Ana
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ana.df1` instead. It is a class's variable, so you first specify a class instance (or a class itself) and then `df1`

```
a = Ana()
a.df1
```

If you define `df1` in the function `Upload`, you can add `df1` to return values like this

```
def upload(args):
    #your code
    return your_return, df1
```

So now you can get df1 with `return_value, df1 = Ana.upload()`

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'df1' when writing that

Comment: @andrew_helpme could you please share your `Ana` code in the question?

Comment: @andrew_helpme maybe now I've answered your question?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean with 'So now you can get df1 with return_value, df1 = Ana.upload()'

Comment: @andrew_helpme if `upload` already returns something and you don't want to lose it, you can return multiple variables [read here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-41-multiple-return-values-in-python/). if `upload` does not return anything now, then just write `df1 = Ana.upload()` and `return df1` in `upload` itself