# NameError: name 'FunctionName' is not defined

Tags: python

I have two files. One named MainMenu.py another named MissionMenu.py for a simple text game I was making. But I ran into an issue (I'm still rather new to this) that is giving me a NameError:.

The first file looks like this

```
from MissionMenu import *
def mainMenu():
    x = input("Type Something:")
    missionMenu()
mainMenu()
```

The second File looks like this

```
from MainMenu import *
def missionMenu():
    x = input("Type something else:")
    mainMenu()
missionMenu()
```

The error says
NameError: name 'missionMenu' is not defined

Comment: Oh no, that's not how import works, you don't include .py while importing...

Comment: kindly look at: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Comment: Next time, please say which snippet is located on which file, that will help a lot...

Comment: Figured it was obvious which snippet was located on which file.

Answer (score 0):

look at this: [Call a function from another file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python)

You are using `import` incorrectly. Yo don't need to add .py

```py
from MissionMenu import missionMenu
def mainMenu():
    x = input("Type Something:")
    missionMenu()
mainMenu()
```

also, it's a bad idea in each file to import the other. kind of circular loop. Think which file really needs the other one. Probably they don't need to import each other

Comment: There is no way of looping between files?

Comment: it's a bad design, even you could. It can cause circular dependencies. Every script should have different purpose

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need a .py.

Suppose, If you have a file a.py and inside you have some functions:

```
def b():
  # Something
  return 1

def c():
  # Something
  return 2
```

And you want to import them in z.py you have to write

`from a import b, c`

Source and Details : [Call a function from another file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Two issues about your code:

### Imports

To import a file called `MainMenu.py`:

`import MainMenu`

So **do not use** `.py` after that name.

### Dependencies

You should keep your dependencies straight:

- Do not import `MissionMenu` from `MainMenu` that imports `MissionMenu`
- Just keep it simple ^^

**Edit:**

If you want to have multiple scripts that contain different menus,
just create a function in those scripts (they are called `modules` then).

Import them in your main application (don't import the main script in the `module`) and run the function from the main file.

Hope this is helpful ^^

Comment: There is no way of returning to the original file?

Comment: @ElderSapling I added a section in my answer, telling you how to use code from multiple files