# How to run python file inside another python file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How do I make this python code containing kivy run in another python code containing kivy like you would call a function so I can have different segment of the code. I don't want too much code on a particular python file because I would be dealing with large code.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import Floatlayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.label import Label 


class LandingScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

         
        self.btn1=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b1))
        self.btn2=Button(text='button2', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b2))


            
        self.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)

        def click_b1(self, instance):
             
             pass
        def click_b2(self, instance):
             pass
       
class SplashApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LandingScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SplashApp().run()
```

How do I call this python file inside this other python file below supposed the first file is a.py and the second file is b.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import Floatlayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.label import Label 


class LandingScreen2(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen2, self).__init__(**kwargs)

         
        self.btn3=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b3))
        self.btn4=Button(text='button2', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b4))


            
        self.add_widget(self.btn3)
        self.add_widget(self.btn4)

        def click_b3(self, instance):
             
             pass
        def click_b4(self, instance):
             pass
       
class SplashApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LandingScreen2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SplashApp().run()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python and https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its called `import`. you can import the second module , say `b.py` in your current module and call the entry point of this module.

in `a.py`

```
import b
...
...
#call b.py entry point.
b.SplashApp().run()
```

you can do something extra ordinary, spawning anew process and call b.py with python via the shell (but this is extraordinary, and i mention this just to let you know that you can do what ever u like with python)

```
import subprocess
p= subprocess.Popen("python b.py",shell=True)
p.communicate
```

Answer (score 0):

To call another file, you treat it just like a module, you would use:

```py
#a.py
import b
b.execute()
```

```py
#b.py
def execute() :
    print("This works!")
```

All variables and functions would need to have the prefix `b.` to reference the "module" as you can see in the example

#### This question is a possible duplicate of:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files