# Can I call multiple functions from a .py file without having to import each one individually?

Tags: python, file, module

If I had a file.py file

```
func1()
func2()
func3()
func4()
func5()
```

Is there a way to just import the whole file

```
import file
```

and call out the functions when needed instead of

```
from file import func1, func2, func3, func4, func5
```

Comment: `from file import *`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a function from another file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python)

Comment: other option is `import file` and then call `file.func1()` `file.func2()` etc. in my opinion it's better because it's make the code more readable as long as you must explicity set the origin of the function.

Comment: Actually, you can control what `from file import *` imports by defining what names are "public" an `__all__` list in the `file` module script. See [The `import` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=__all__#the-import-statement) in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your `import file` statement, you actually already have access to all of the functions inside `file.py`, you simply need to preface them with the name of the file you imported, ie:

```py
import file

file.func1()
file.func2()
etc...
```

If you truly wish not to have to preface where those functions came from (even though it is considered best practice to do so), `from file import *` is the answer you're looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, import the file, then get each function by its name:

```
import file

func_names = ['func1', 'func2', ...]
for name in func_names:
    getattr(file, name)()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind moving your functions into a class as methods, you could import the class in your other module:

```
#module_one.py
class MyMethods:

    @staticmethod
    def method1():
        return 'Hello world!'

    @staticmethod
    def method2():
        return True


#module_two.py
from .module_one import MyMethods

x = MyMethods.method1()
y = MyMethods.method2()
```

Comment: this is superfluous to the original question, and the exact same behaviour is achieved simply by importing module_one, then calling module_one.func1(), module_one.func2() ... etc