# How can I call up this function properly?(Also it has now been fully resolved I no longer need help for this)

Tags: python

```
#functions
def main_menu():
    print('If you want to read the rules select:1, to play the game select:2, to quit select 3.')
    branch = int(input('What do you want to do:\n'))
menu = input('Type: main_menu()\n')
while branch == 1:
    print('Hello to the rules')
    main_menu
while branch == 2:
    print(branch)
```

This will later become a number guessing game, where the function calls up the main menu, any help to call up the function?

Comment: This question is not clear about the obstacle you encountered. Is this the first time you try to call a function? Did you try calling the function like other functions? With what result? Do you have problems with the needed context in which to call? Please have a look at [ask] and generally [tour].

Answer (score 0):

```
from library import function_name
```

This is how you can load in main and than utilize where you want.

as a reference, I am giving you link below.

[importing function from library or file to main file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
def main_menu():
    print('If you want to read the rules select:1, to play the game select:2, to quit select 3.')
    branch = int(input('What do you want to do:\n'))
menu = input('Type: main_menu()\n')
while branch == 1:
    print('Hello to the rules')
    main_menu
while branch == 2:
    print(branch)
main_menu() # just do this
```

That's how you call a function in Python.
Add a () in the function name

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
main_menu()
```

That's how you call a function in Python.