# How to import your own .py file as a module to another .py file in sublime

Tags: python

I have a ex.py file, where i defined several functions.
Now, I'm trying to import ex.py to another sorter.py file as a module to use those functions.

So, inside of sorter.py, I have:

```
import ex
function_name()
```

NameError: name 'function_name' is not defined

So, I suppose, i don't have ex.py imported to sorter.py

Both .py files are in the same directory, which is not childdir for python or sublime installation folder.
I tried to insert the path to ex.py into sys.path, but that didn't help.
How can i fix that, considering, that I'm using **sublime text editor**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20309473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use functions defined in ex.py you either need to import them directly:

```
from ex import function_name()
from ex import *
```

Or refer to the function as a part of ex:

```
ex.function_name()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use:

```
ex.function_name()
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check if they are located in the same folder in the memory.
then you have to options:

```
import ex
ex.function_name()
```

--OR--

```
from ex import function_name
function_name()
```

You can also import everything from ex and then you won't have to right ex.Sample_Funtion. This can be done by:

```
from ex import *
#imports everything

function_name()
another_function_in_ex()
```

Comment: Don't forget what the [Style Guide for Python Code says about wildcard imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports): "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."

Comment: Agreed. We should only follow this practice only when we are explicitly using another class in our code, then these types of imports can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply import function_name from ex file and call it:

```
from ex import function_name
function_name()
```

Comment: Hi ad0min. Great choice to start with Python if you might want to go further https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_modules.asp #welcomeonboard