# How to get dictionary data through a python module?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, module

```
def cd():
     person = {
    'name' : 'bhavya',
    'age' : 32,
    'birth_date' : '18/10/1996'
    }
    print(person)

cd()
```

This is a dictionary I've saved as ey.py.
Now I want to import this whole data into another .py file with help of a module. So I can fetch whole data saved in ey.py.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Please put more detail into your question. It is very unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: IIUC, your goal is seperating data from main python file. Is it right?

Comment: Create a dict inside a function named hello and save the file --- Then create a new file and write import hello from the file name. Now when i import the function all i want is to access single data such as name or age that's all i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is separating data from main python code, you have to make a new python code(ex. `data.py`)

**data.py**

```py
def get_data():
    data = { 'name' : 'bhavya', 'age' : 32, 'birth_date' : '18/10/1996' }
    return data
```

**main.py**

```py
from data import get_data

person = get_data()
print(person)
```

[FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file)

Comment: what if i want to access values of age

Comment: For access value of key in dictionary, `person['age']`.