# Save and Load a function in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a function in python, which I want to be able to use in many different scripts.

Can I save this and then load in?

So the function is

```
def dosomething(x):
     do something
```

I want to save this as a file in my documents

```
file=r/xxx/xxx/dosomething.py
```

Then in a new script I want to load it in and use it

New Script

```
    df=data
    
    load_function(path=file)

    df=df.apply(dosomething)
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a function from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `import` statement.
for example if your script is called `actions.py`:

```
from actions import do_something
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible like below.

```py
# Custom Script Path: /Users/mert/workspace/my_func.py

def say_hello(name):
    print(f"Hello {name}")
```

```py
# Your another project folder

import sys
sys.path.append('path-to-your-func-folder')

import my_func
my_func.say_hello('Mert')

# Output
>> Hello Mert
```

Comment: you shouldn't modify sys.path