# Python unittest with test/ and src/ not finding src modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I have a simple directory structure:

```
proj/
    src/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        test_foo.py
```

test_foo.py

```
import unittest

import sys
sys.path.append('../src')

from src import foo

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_foo(self):
    foo.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

foo.py

```
import bar

def start():
  bar.do_stuff()
```

When running my test (I'm using vscode), I get the following error:

```
Failed to import test module: test_foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "~/proj/test/test_foo.py", line 6, in <module>
    from src import foo
  File "~/proj/src/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'
```

I'm not sure why the test can't discover the src/bar when importing src/foo

Comment: From test_foo.py you use "from src import foo" then from foo.py you only use "import bar". I would be suspicious of your proj/src/__init__.py.

Comment: the `__init__.py` are just empty files

Comment: It might also be a good idea to rename `test/` to `tests/` to avoid conflicting with the python built-in `test`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `import bar` try `from src import bar`.

```py
from src import bar


def start():
    bar.do_stuff()
```

**Notice**

Keep in mind, that you only adjusted the path in the test. You do not want the tests to work, but the application to fail because you forgot to adjust the path in the application at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Two changes：

1. `from src import bar` in `foo.py`,
2. before import modules in `test_foo.py`, add

   ```
    import sys  
    sys.path.append("./")
   ```

Then you should be able to run code successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is in your `bar.py` file?  Just the `do_stuff()` function?  Or is the `do_stuff()` function a method of object `bar`?

Depending on the answer to the question above, try doing something like this in your `foo.py` file:

```py
from proj.src.bar import [name of function you're testing here]
```

In your specific case, it would be like this if `do_stuff()` is a standalone function:

```py
from proj.src.bar import do_stuff
```

and then your `foo.py` file would be:

```py
from proj.src.bar import do_stuff

def stuff():
  do_stuff()
```

However, if `do_stuff()` is a method of the `bar` object, it would probably be something like this, although it's hard to tell without knowing the contents of the `bar.py` file:

```py
from proj.src.bar import bar
```

and then your `foo.py` file would be similar to the way you have it now:

```py
from proj.src.bar import bar

def stuff():
  bar.do_stuff()
```

I recently ran into a similar problem when trying to import one neighboring file into another.  This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/call-a-function-from-another-file) helped me out, too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had imports of modules which are not actually installed, in my `bar.py` file, such as:

```
import requests
```

After installing those modules, VSCode showed tests properly.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. It's seems to be that python unable to idenitfy the src directory as a package. So I developed 'src' as a package by creatiing a setup.py file and run it to create package distribution format.It fiexed the error.  You can create 'egg' ( older format) or 'wheel' file format.  Hope this helps